# error trying to consume the back-end using react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, frontend, backend

I'm trying to consume but I've been receiving an error:
{error: {…}}
error
:
{clientVersion: '4.9.0'} but my api is working. I can't consume it on front-end

I put many console logs when I submit and the result is

{firstName: 'Matheus', lastName: 'Coppi', role: 'enginner', age: '23', email: 'matheus@gmail', …}

Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:8080/register', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

{error: {…}}
error: {clientVersion: '4.9.0'}

The error is my catch from my api

```
 async createUser(req, res) {
        try {
            const {
                firstName,
                lastName,
                role,
                age,
                email,
                password
            } = req.body

            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
            console.log(salt)

            const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
            console.log(hash)

            const verifyemail = await prisma.UserInfo.findUnique({
                where: {
                    email
                }
            })

            if (verifyemail) {
                return res.send({
                    "error": "true"
                })
            }

            const user = await prisma.UserInfo.create({
                data: {
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    role: role,
                    age: age,
                    email: email,
                    password: hash
                }
            });

            return res.send(user)

        } catch (error) {
            return res.json({ error }) // The error client version is from here

        }
    }
```

Here is my react front-end

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
const Register = () => {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
    const [lastName, setlastName] = useState('')
    const [role, setRole] = useState('')
    const [age, setAge] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        const info = {firstName, lastName, role, age, email, password}
        console.log(info)

        fetch("http://localhost:8080/register", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(info)
    }).then(async response => {
        console.log(response) //until here it works
        try {
         const data = await response.json()
         console.log(data)
            
       } catch(error) {
         console.log('Error happened here!')
         console.error(error)
       }
      })
    }
        
    
    return ( 
        <div className='all1'>
        <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="First Name" value={firstName} onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}/>

          <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value={lastName} onChange={(e) => setlastName(e.target.value)} />

          <Form.Label>Role</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="role" value={role} onChange={(e) => setRole(e.target.value)}/>

          <Form.Label>Age</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="number" placeholder="age" value={age} onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}/>

          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
          <Form.Text className="text-muted">
            We'll never share your email with anyone else.
          </Form.Text>
        </Form.Group>
  
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>

         
        </Form.Group>
        
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
      </div>
      <div>{email}</div>
      <div>{password}</div>
      </div>
     );
}
 
export default Register;
```

Comment: If I try to add with an email that was created send the error from api when this email was created "error": "true", but if I change and put a valid email does not work

Comment: If you add `console.error("create user", error)` to your backend code (before `return res.json({ error })`), do you see any extra detail in your terminal / server logs?

Comment: Even with that i was receiving the error client version ‘4.9.0’

Comment: I change the error on my back-end catch to return res.json({ "error": "error" }) and now is catching "error": "error" in my console